# Remove numbers inside parenthesis in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains data like

```
column1
-----------
Hello (120)
234
World (22
```

I am trying to remove all the parts like `(120)` or `(22`. The code I have written is:

```
df['column1'] = df['column1'].str.replace(r"\((\d+)\)", "", regex = True)
df['column1'] = df['column1'].str.replace(r"\((\d+)", "", regex = True)
```

My expected output is:

```
column1
--------
Hello 
234
World
```

But what I am getting is:

```
column1
--------
Hello 

World
```

Can anyone explain to me why `234` is being removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
>>> df['column1'].str.replace(r"\s*\(\d+\)?", "", regex=True)
0    Hello
1      234
2    World
Name: column1, dtype: object
```

Your code works well for me except for whitespace before '('

Answer (score 0):

Try the pattern `\s*\(\d+(?:\))?`. It will replace anything that starts with one or more white space and an opening parenthesis containing digits, ending with/without the closing parenthesis

```py
>>> df['column1'].str.replace('\s*\(\d+(?:\))?', '', regex=True)

0    Hello
1      234
2    World
Name: column1, dtype: object
```

Comment: @Corralien, there is no capturing group in the regex, if  you are trying to point the part `(?:\))?`, again that's not a capturing group

Comment: Sorry, I think I need new glasses :-)

Comment: *A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or referenced later in the pattern.* from docs for `(?:...)`